# Legend no longer "in-bar" in fieldset when hyperlink present

Tags: html

In a box created with fieldset:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> Legend </legend>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum, etc.
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

This displays initially just as want it:

```
+-- Legend --------
| Lorem ipsum, etc.
```

I find that as soon as I add an anchor (a href=...), as here:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> Legend </legend>
  <p>
  Lorem <a href="http://www.ipsum.com">ipsum</a>, etc.
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

then legend text is forced down into the box more or less thus:

```
+---------------
| Legend
| Lorem <a href="http://www.ipsum.com">ipsum</a>, etc.
```

Is there something that can be done to prevent this from happening, that is, keep the legend appearing in the fieldset border?

Comment: Seems to work like it should over here, even with anchors in the text, are you sure you didn't just mistype something?

Comment: This began to happen to me a few years ago or, at least, I had never noticed it before. I'm just getting around to being annoyed by it. I'm not a web page developer, but a software engineer who writes HTML on occasion, so it may be I just need to stop being casual about finding a solution.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add html that 'breaks' as you describe?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Of course, it could also be my fault. In fact, it was. I was able to make a smaller and small example from a failing one until I isolated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had a name anchor just before my fieldset thus:

```
<a name="name" />
<fieldset>
  <legend> Legend </legend>
  <p>
  Lorem <a href="http://www.ipsum.com">ipsum</a>, etc.
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Changing it to

```
<a name="name"></a>
<fieldset>
  <legend> Legend </legend>
  <p>
  Lorem <a href="http://www.ipsum.com">ipsum</a>, etc.
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

solved the problem. I thought the form I was using was correct HTML though I think this is discontinued in HTML 5.